# spree commerce adding product

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm using spree commerce to a store. I want to keep the admin panel simple.

Ex : Admin can add product without the need of any properties and other things

As we will be displaying only the product name and the quantity in the storefront

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it it, you don't have to add any properties for product. As i remember most important things for product are: name, available_on, price,  shipping_category. And you have to have stock or do not track_inventory. 
But remember when you are creating Product you also create master variant. 
It is also nice to have all meta_data.

If you want to you can override admin product views and create them as you want. [Product Views](https://github.com/spree/spree/tree/master/backend/app/views/spree/admin/products)

Comment: Can a user create product with providing product name, Image, Quantity. Can he create with entering these details. because the its ask to tag option types etc. ?

Comment: Hi, option type and option value are needed to create variant of product. For example color(ot) -> black (ov). Admin can create product providing name, price, shipping category. Then he has to add stock, and available_on to has product in shop. Images are not needed, but can be added later in images view (option for ALL is for master variant). If you want to have one page 'new product' you have to customize it. As i know, not Admin user cannot create product.